# Both events on focus, is JS needed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't figure out how to get both of these effects (see code snippet below) on inputs using focus. I noticed that the focus works only for this element which is first in line. Can someone tell me why? And is it possible to get both effects on focus without using JavaScript?

```css
form {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.expand {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"] {
  border: none;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 280px;
}

.border {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  background: red;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: #999;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus + .border,
input[type="email"]:focus + .border {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

input[type="text"]:focus + label,
input[type="email"]:focus + label {
  top: -10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="expand">
    <input type="text" name="" id="">
    <!-- border before label -->
    <div class="border"></div>
    <label for="">Here works border effect</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="expand">
    <input type="email" name="" id="">
    <!-- border after label -->
    <label for="">Here works label effect</label>
    <div class="border"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the `+` selector only the *direct* sibling will be affected, instead use `~`

```css
form {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.expand {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
textarea {
  border: none;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 280px;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.border {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  background: red;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: #999;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus ~ .border,
input[type="email"]:focus ~ .border,
textarea:focus ~ .border {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

input[type="text"]:focus ~ label,
input[type="email"]:focus ~ label,
textarea:focus ~ label {
  top: -10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="expand">
    <input type="text" name="" id="">
    <!-- border before label -->
    <div class="border"></div>
    <label for="">Here works border effect</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="expand">
    <input type="email" name="" id="">
    <!-- border after label -->
    <label for="">Here works label effect</label>
    <div class="border"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3nw7mkfe/1/

You can concatenate selector + like > or ~ or other.

```
<form action="">
  <div class="expand">
    <input type="email" name="" id="">
    <!-- border after label -->
    <label for="">Here works label effect</label>
    <div class="border"></div>
  </div>
</form>

form {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.expand {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
textarea {
  border: none;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 280px;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.border {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  background: red;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: #999;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus + label + .border,
input[type="email"]:focus + label + .border,
textarea:focus + .border {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

input[type="text"]:focus + label,
input[type="email"]:focus + label,
textarea:focus + label {
  top: -10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, something like that but for two inputs :) Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your effective selectors are `input:focus + .border` and `input:focus + label` (with two types of inputs, but that does not matter for the working). The [`+` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) only selects the adjacent sibling. If you want to make it work independent of the order of the label and border, you should use the [general sibling selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors). That would select any sibling after the selected element, not just the adjacent one.

Thus, your selectors will become `input:focus ~ .border` and `input:focus ~ label`. Hope that helps.

A good overview of selectors and combinators is given at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). There are some pretty powerful ones!

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for what you need

```css
form {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.expand {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
textarea {
  border: none;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 280px;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.border {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  background: red;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: #999;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus + label + .border,
input[type="email"]:focus + label + .border,
textarea:focus + .border {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

input[type="text"]:focus + label,
input[type="email"]:focus + label,
textarea:focus + label {
  top: -10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="">   
  <div class="expand">
    <input type="email" name="" id="">
    <!-- border after label -->
    <label for="">Here works label effect</label>
    <div class="border"></div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="expand">
    <input type="email" name="" id="">
    <!-- border after label -->
    <label for="">Here works label effect</label>
    <div class="border"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Check this it will work as you need